# ffmpeg txt from audio levels

Tags: csv, audio, ffmpeg

Regards community,

I want to use **ffmpeg** to generate a file (txt, csv) from audio values.
Any idea?

I use this code to generate the audio levels:

```
ffplay -f lavfi "amovie=input.aac, asplit [a][out1]; [a] showvolume=f=1:b=4:w=800:h=70 [out0]"
```

[image: Show volume]

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 13):

The command below will generate a CSV format where the first column represents the audio frame time in seconds, the second column the overall RMS dB volume for that frame, the 3rd column RMS volume for the first channel and the last column the RMS volume for the 2nd channel.

```
ffprobe -f lavfi -i amovie=input.aac,astats=metadata=1:reset=1 -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time:frame_tags=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level,lavfi.astats.1.RMS_level,lavfi.astats.2.RMS_level -of csv=p=0
```

Output:

```
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.023220, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_f64le, 44100 Hz, stereo, dbl, 5644 kb/s
0.023220,-inf,-inf,-inf
0.046440,-inf,-inf,-inf
0.069660,-inf,-inf,-inf
0.092880,-27.330401,-22.685612,-24.414572
0.116100,-21.141091,-18.986082,-19.931269
0.139320,-20.955719,-18.549085,-19.587788
0.162540,-20.938002,-18.198237,-19.355561
0.185760,-19.852306,-20.032553,-19.941494
0.208980,-20.495281,-21.684953,-21.049508
```

The `reset` determines how often the stats are calculated. I've set the value to `1` i.e. calculated for each audio frame in isolation.

Comment: Really grateful,
Is there a way to export it to a file (.txt or .csv)?

Comment: Sure. Add `1> log.txt` at the end.

Comment: Excellent Malvya nice to meet you, I'm sorry for another question. Where can I find documentation to do the same with video levels (YCbCr)?       I've got it solved on the side playback (ffplay)

Comment: Can you post it as a new question, explaining specifically what you require?

Comment: Is there a way to use this with an rtsp stream from an IP camera?

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, really appreciate your answer